# Does Cpanel have search capabilies using site ground hosting?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have been working with phpmyadmin in XAMPP for some time now and I'd like to switch to Cpannel. I was looking at siteground as a web host, but I'm worries about if I search things. Im working with a IOS app and I need to have a search page where users can search for song in my database. Does anyone know if this is possible with Ccannel for a IOS app? Also I have macOS Catalina so do I have linux on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow; here specific questions are better that have a portion of code that isn't working right. This is more of an opinion question that is difficult to answer in the Stack Overflow format. Also, you've asked several questions which makes it hard for some people to give responses to only partial answers.

However, basically yes, this is possible. There are many ways you could do this, the way I suggest is to have an API exposed on the web server, which would then directly interact with the database. Your app will connect to the API for database queries.

MacOS isn't really Linux (it's based off of BSD, which is similar to Linux in many ways), but it's close enough for many purposes and many Linux applications run just fine on MacOS.

> I have been working with phpmyadmin in XAMPP for some time now and I'd like to switch to Cpannel

These aren't quite similar, XAMPP is a prepackaged kit for installing Apache, MySQL, PHP, and Perl in one installer where everything gets installed together and works out of the box. In comparison, cPanel is more intended as a web hosting control panel. With cPanel, you can control those software products, but the target audiences of the two platforms are somewhat different.

Aside from that, if you have a hosting provider that provides a VPS or some other virtualized platform, you can install whatever you want (such as just the parts of Apache/nginx, MySQL/MariaDB, and PHP that you'll actually use) as well as your own custom software to expose the API interface to your iOS app.

By the way, directly exposing your database to the web or accessing it directly from your app are bad ideas for multiple reasons, including security and latency.